# Maintaining scroll position when concatenating data without content move

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working to fetch more content when the user reaches the top(infinite scroll). I have implemented all logic but when I update the state, the scroll always moves to the top. I want to maintain the screen position without moving the content even  for a small millisecond because it creates a bad impact on the user. I have written the code which you can see on. Currently is fluctuating for bit.
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/recursing-heyrovsky-jqty95?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A17%2C25).

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

const para =
  "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).";

export default function Test() {
  const containerRef = useRef(null);

  const [paras, setParas] = useState(
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10].map((x, i) => `${i}---- ${para}`)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      const scrollHeightBefore = containerRef.current.scrollHeight;
      setParas((pa) => [`${pa.length + 1}---- ${para}`, ...pa]);
      setTimeout(() => {
        const scrollHeightAfter = containerRef.current.scrollHeight;
        console.log(scrollHeightBefore, scrollHeightAfter);

        window.scrollBy(0, scrollHeightAfter - scrollHeightBefore);
      }, 200);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div ref={containerRef}>
      {paras.map((item, i) => (
        <p>{item}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```